# Is the CUDA API version and driver version always the same

Tags: cuda

The CUDA version obtained from `cuDriverGetVersion`, and the API version from the macro `CUDA_VERSION`.
Are they supposed to be always the same (assuming CUDA is correctly installed)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CUDA_VERSION` macro tells you which version of the CUDA API you are *compiling* your code against. `cuDriverGetVersion()` will tell you the most recent version of CUDA that the driver you're *running* with supports. So no, they don't have to be the same. For example, an application that was compiled for CUDA 9.x will run perfectly fine with a driver that supports CUDA 10…